# Uploading a cover photo to a facebook event on creation using the facebook event API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Using the events API I have the following code to post my event with an event photo

```
  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      "appId"      => "XXX",
      "secret"     => "XXX",
      "cookie"     => false,
      "fileUpload" => true
  ));

  $data = array("name"=>$eventTitle,
                "start_time"=>$startTime,
                "description"=>$description,
                "privacy_type"=>$privacyType,
                 basename($fileName) => '@'.$fileName
  );

  $result = $facebook->api("/me/events","post",$data);
```

I'm interested in uploading a cover photo and I haven't found a clear way to do so with the PHP sdk. I've tried `"source" => '@'.$coverPhoto`, `"cover" => '@'.$coverPhoto`, `"cover_url" => '@'.$coverPhoto` and:

```
  $data = array("name"=>$eventTitle,
                "start_time"=>$startTime,
                "description"=>$description,
                "privacy_type"=>$privacyType,
                 basename($fileName) => '@'.$fileName,
                 "cover" => array(
                    "source" => '@'.$coverPhoto
                 )
  );
```

But I can't seem to find the right way to push in a cover photo. Any ideas?

Comment: you're trying to add profile cover photo or event photo ?

Comment: Actually, I didn't understand the question. Are you trying to upload one of your cover pic as an event's picture?

Comment: I'm trying to upload an event cover photo (so the photo at the top) which is different from the event photo (displayed on the left)

Comment: Are you sure about it? Because I see only one type of picture for events that is the event picture.

Comment: @RahilArora so it looks like there are two different types of event designs from facebook. Both designs have the ability to add cover photos, the older design allows you to upload a cover after the event was created with the API, the new version doesn't allow you to edit the photos after the event was created. Old layout: http://oi43.tinypic.com/fjj6tc.jpg. New layout: http://oi39.tinypic.com/4hrsbp.jpg

Comment: I see. I think both the designs allow you to upload only one picture that is the event picture. The difference I guess is in the positioning of the picture. Older design showed it in the form of Profile picture while newer design shows it in the form of a cover picture.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't do it as of now.

There are two event related endpoints in Graph API: `/{event-id}` and `/{user-id}/events` and according to the [Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/), none of them provide a support to upload the Event cover picture. Also, the documentation does not mention anything about support to upload the event photo (which, I assume, you were successfully able to do with your code).

However, based on the official Graph API documentation and my knowledge of Graph API, it's currently not possible to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The method described in the official [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/picture/#publish) to upload a cover photo of an event don't work as of now. I've reported this as a bug. You can subscribe to this [**bug**](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/274455709396178/) to get any updates regarding the same.

The **only** way to do this (as of now)-

Firstly, you cant do this upload cover pic while creating an event. You first have to create an event, as a result you'll get the `event_id`. Use this `event_id`, to make a call:

`\POST /{event-id}` with param: `cover_url`

**Code:**

```
$param = array(
    'cover_url' => '{image-link}'
);

$facebook->api('/{event-id}', 'POST', $param);
```